# FInding the tangent line horizontal to a curve of $\frac{1}{(x^2-16)(x-7)}$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Determine the values of  x where the tangent line is horizontal for the function:$$\frac {1}{(x^2-16)(x-7)}$$ 
The value(s) of $x$ where the tangent line to the graph of the function is horizontal is(are)***_***.

The Derivative of the $f(x)$ is
$$f'(x)=\frac{-3x^2+14x-16}{(x-7)^2(x^2-16)^2}$$

Comment: Find the roots of the equation $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thus the “question” is answered perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To get better help, please, provide your own thoughts on the subject. Simply demanding an answer without showing some personal effort is not an option - your question will be put on hold and eventually closed.

Comment: There’s a sign error in the last term of the numerator of your derivative; if you fix that and recompute the roots, you should be okay.

Answer (score 3):

You are *almost* on the right track (your numerator should be $-3x^2+14x+16$). Once you've fixed that, you'll want to figure out when the numerator of the derivative is $0$.

A good thing to keep in mind when dealing with rational functions is this: for a tangent line to exist at a point (horizontal or otherwise), the function *must be defined at that point*. So, we'll need to toss out solutions to $f'(x)=0$ that are not in the domain of $f(x)$ (if there are any such solutions).

Comment: Good catch, Brian! Thanks for the heads up.